# How does Godaddy Store PayPal as a payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

When I checkout with GoDaddy (among other websites) I can choose from a list of PayPal accounts to pay with that I have already approved for payment methods.

The amount is always different and can be used as a backup payment method.

My question is how is this done? I have a site and I can setup subscriptions and accept paypal, but I see no way of allowing a customer to simply approve a charge from my site and me processing it automatically and then sending them to the receipt page without sending them to at least one paypal page.

With the sites like GoDaddy is just goes straight to the receipt page.

I see that I can use the REST API and Accept Payment with a PaymentID. Can I simply use the REST API in a different manner than I'm seeing to do this with?

Answer (score 0):

When you check out with Godaddy via Express Checkout, they pass a parameter telling the checkout process to offer a billing agreement between the customer and Godaddy, which the customer then agrees to (it is a checkbox and line of text above the "Pay" button, which changes to "Agree and Pay").

Billing agreements never expire unless one side chooses to cancel it.

Requesting a billing agreement from a customer requires the receiver's PayPal account to be approved for Reference Transactions, which are then used to create future transactions via the DoReferenceTransaction API call.  RTs are powerful and could be misused, which is why their availability is subject to approval.  Contact PayPal Business Support or an account manager for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I will contact PayPal and get this set up. So is there a special variable that I have to pass through in order to setup billing agreement once approved via PayPal to use it?